# Export Analytics from Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

There are analytics pages in the Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard (for example, "Installs & uninstalls" and "Users"). Those pages contain different visualizations (for example, "Enabled vs. disabled" on [Analytics] [Users] page) and buttons "Export to CSV" before each visualization.

Is there a way to automatically export the analytics to Google Sheets, Google Analytics or export in CSV format every day?